# WooCommerce checkout: How can I change $field_container of a checkout field?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

By default the checkout fields are wrapped inside `<p class="form-row...` HTML by the `woocommerce_form_field()` core function (see `$field_container`) - I want to change that bahaviour. How could this be done without altering the core function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `woocommerce_form_field()` is a [pluggable](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions) function, [defined](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_form_field.html#2066-2278) as follows:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_form_field' ) ) {

    /**
     * Outputs a checkout/address form field.
     *
     * @param string $key Key.
     * @param mixed  $args Arguments.
     * @param string $value (default: null).
     * @return string
     */
    function woocommerce_form_field( $key, $args, $value = null ) {
        ...
    }
}
```

So you can copy the [whole](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_form_field.html#2066-2278) code into your theme's *functions.php* file, and modify the form field wrapper to suit your requirements, like so where I changed the wrapper's tag from `p` to `div`:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_form_field' ) ) {

    /**
     * Outputs a checkout/address form field.
     *
     * @param string $key Key.
     * @param mixed  $args Arguments.
     * @param string $value (default: null).
     * @return string
     */
    function woocommerce_form_field( $key, $args, $value = null ) {
        ...
        $field_container = '<div class="form-row %1$s" id="%2$s" data-priority="' . esc_attr( $sort ) . '">%3$s</div>';

        switch ( $args['type'] ) {
            ...
            case 'state':
                ...

                if ( is_array( $states ) && empty( $states ) ) {

                    $field_container = '<div class="form-row %1$s" id="%2$s" style="display: none">%3$s</div>';

                    ...

                } ...
            ...
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

*Or* you can use the `woocommerce_form_field` filter, like so (here I used [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to change the wrapper's tag from `p` to `div`):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field', 'my_woocommerce_form_field' );
function my_woocommerce_form_field( $field ) {
    return preg_replace(
        '#<p class="form-row (.*?)"(.*?)>(.*?)</p>#',
        '<div class="form-row $1 test"$2>$3</div>',
        $field
    );
}
```

The alternate method worked well *in my case*, but of course, there were no other (plugin, theme, or custom) code that changes the wrapper's markup/HTML.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Just one more question: How did you find out that it is a pluggable function? I mean the list in the link provided by you states only WP functions, without any reference to woocommerce. So how could I recognize a pluggable function in future?

Comment: That link is for a generic intro to pluggable functions. The key point is, if you see `if ( ! function_exists('{FUNCTION NAME}') )`, the function is pluggable, which means you can override it by defining it before a theme or plugin defines it. See [this](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/set-up-and-use-a-child-theme/#section-8), though that's not a reference of WC's pluggable functions. :)